# Conectar telnet con Weblogic en Aix

Tags: java

Buenas

Tengo un problema con una aplicación desarrollada en java 1.5 hace algunos años

Lo que pasa es que tengo 600 terminales que se conectan con un jar que esta instalado en un sistema operativo AIX vía telnet y este jar se comunica con un servidor webLogic 12c. El problema que tengo es que al conectar mis terminales al sistema operativo se abre una sección de sistema sistema operativo por cada terminal haciendo que mi aplicación tenga problemas

No se si alguien ha tenido experiencia con este tema y me pueda colaborar o dar una idea de como utilizo la conexión telnet sin tener tantas conexiones al sistema operativo(AIX)abiertas

Saludos

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Te recomiendo describir los problemas que tu aplicación experimenta al `"tener tantas conexiones abiertas"`. De lo contrario, tu pregunta podría ser cerrada por la comunidad por falta de claridad.

Comment: Tantas conexiones al Sistema operativo AIX